# Reading samplerate from a wavfile header

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I am writing code to read in a wave file.

I am using [this document](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) as my guideline.

It specifies that byte 22 of the header is the number of channels of the wave files, and byte 24 of the header is the sample rate.

I am using a test file that was output by Ableton as 2 channel 16 bit 44100hz. I have confirmed that the format of the test wave file is audacity to be sure it is indeed 44100hz samplerate.

When I read in the wave file, I get a sample rate value of -21436. I am quite certain that my code that reads in a little endian integer is correct. And I am certain that my test wavfile is correct. So now I am out of idea's as to why the read samplerate is incorrect....

my int reading code is as follows.

```
int ReadInt(char* bytes , int start) { return (bytes[start+3] << 24) + (bytes[start+2] << 16) + (bytes[start+1] << 8) + bytes[start]; }
```

The function that reads the wave file is as follows...

```
WavFile::WavFile(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs;      
    ifs.open( filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in );

    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile::WavFile - - - - BEGIN READING WAV - - - -";

    if(ifs.fail())
        throw std::invalid_argument("WavFile::WavFile : Failed to open wavFile "+filename);

    char hbytes[HEADER_SIZE];

    ifs.read(hbytes , HEADER_SIZE);

    // check that this is actually a wave file
    bool valid_riff = hbytes[0]=='R' && hbytes[1]=='I' && hbytes[2]=='F' && hbytes[3]=='F';
    bool valid_wave = hbytes[8]=='W' && hbytes[9]=='A' && hbytes[10]=='V' && hbytes[11]=='E';
    bool valid_ftm = (hbytes[12]=='f' && hbytes[13]=='m' && hbytes[14]=='t' && hbytes[15]==' ');
    bool valid_data = (hbytes[36]=='d' && hbytes[37]=='a' && hbytes[38]=='t' && hbytes[39]=='a');

    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile::WavFile - valid_riff="<<valid_riff<<" valid_wave="<<valid_wave<<" valid_ftm="<<valid_ftm<<" valid_data="<<valid_data;
    if(!(valid_data && valid_ftm && valid_riff))
        throw std::invalid_argument("WavFile::WavFile : Invalid argument - unable to open wavfile "+filename);

    int audioFormat = ReadShort(hbytes , 20);
    int SubChunk1Size = ReadInt(hbytes , 16);

    if(audioFormat != 1 || SubChunk1Size != 16)
        throw std::invalid_argument("WavFile::WavFile : Only uncompressed PCM wave format supported."+filename);    

    int subChunk2size = ReadInt(hbytes , 40);
    m_header.num_channels = ReadShort(hbytes , 22);
    m_header.sample_rate = ReadInt(hbytes , 24);
    m_header.bits_per_sample = ReadShort(hbytes , 34);

    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile::WavFile num_channels="<<m_header.num_channels << " sample_rate="<<m_header.sample_rate<<" bits_per_sample="<<m_header.bits_per_sample;

    m_pcm_data.resize( subChunk2size / sizeof(int16_t) );

    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile::WavFile - subChunk2size = "<<subChunk2size;
    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile::WavFile - m_pcm_data.size() = "<<m_pcm_data.size();
    ifs.read((char*)m_pcm_data.data() , subChunk2size);

    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile: ifstream failbit="<<ifs.fail()<<" badbit="<<ifs.bad()<<" goodbit="<<ifs.good();

    ifs.close();

    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile::WavFile - - - - END READING WAV - - - -\n";
    LogStream(LOG_DEBUG) << "WavFile::WavFile";
}
```

Comment: If your chars result in negative integers, I'm not sure that adding them will work correctly. Use bitwise or and `unsigned` on your types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

44100 has hex value 44ac (unsigned int16) and -21436 also has hex value 44ac (signed int16) - the problem is with the way the compiler is implicitly casting each signed char to a signed integer before shifting. You can avoid that either by casting as follows (which outputs 44100):

```
int main()
{
    char bytes[4] = { 0x44, 0xac, 0x00, 0x00 };

    printf("%i\n", (((unsigned char)bytes[3]) << 24) | (((unsigned char)bytes[2]) << 16) | (((unsigned char)bytes[1]) << 8) | ((unsigned char)bytes[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

or simply reading as unsigned bytes - this will avoid the same problem for other fields:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char bytes[4] = { 0x44, 0xac, 0x00, 0x00 };

    printf("%i\n", (bytes[3] << 24) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8) | bytes[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: casting the intermediate values to unsigned still gave me a value of -21436. Also I should add that this value is being stored as int. I tried storing as unsigned int and I got a value of 4294945860

Comment: The first solution did not work for me. But the second recommendation solved the problem. Read in to an unsigned char array to begin with.